# Retrieve file relative to play application path

Tags: file, io, playframework

I created a Play! app and deployed it under TomCat. This works well. The only problem is the management of a properties file, currently in the **conf** folder right next to *application.conf*. But as soons as the client replaces the war file the custom properties are overwritten with the default values, resulting in errors.

Now I want to introduce a seperate properties file placed inside the **webapps** folder. This way I will be sure my clients will not overwrite the file 'accidentally'.

So the structure would be:

```
TomCat webapps:
    myPlayApp
    PlayConfig <-- here I want to place the config file
```

So I would like to retrieve the properties file by something like:

```
getFile("../PlayConfig/app.properties");
```

This obvious does not work, but I do not know how to achieve this?
I thought retrieving it by tomcat http url but the portnumber my vary, so this would also not work, I guess...

**UPDATE 2012-01-25:**

Actually when using the following code:

```
Play.applicationPath.getPath();
```

I get the absolute path when running the project outside tomcat (so not inside war file!)

When I deploy the same project in a TomCat server I get the following output:

```
W:\tomcat-5.5\webapps\MyTestProject\WEB-INF\application.
```

From this point on I can indeed use a relative path.

Comment: This will not solve this particular problem but have you thought of persisting the properties in a database instead?

Comment: Yes I have thought about this but I do not want to create a database just for a few properties. And I already have a client database where I get my data out and I cannot put my own things in that client database..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that when deployed in a Servlet container, play uses the  **/WEB-INF/application**  as base directory.
Try changing the path relative to this folder.